# Calculate Information Value and Weight of Evidence in R

Tags: r

I want to ask a question on how to calculate WOE and IV from weighted good bad indicator in R.

I found the **woe** package in R, but it only calculate WOE and IV from non weighted good bad indicator and it seems the indicator must be on 0 and 1 only.

Does anyone knows how to manipulate the good bad indicator in this **woe** package or got information of WOE and IV calculation package with weighted indicator?

Comment: Did you try `InformationValue` package in R? [Helpful link](http://r-statistics.co/Information-Value-With-R.html)